# Choose character as field separator in ember, to avoid conflicts with library internals and handlebars templates

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I put this (question-rant) here for reference for others. I have slight hopes on getting an answer to this, but I still want to describe my experience.

First of all, let me shortly explain my problem: I am porting an application from `ember-data 0.0.14` to `ember-data 1.0.0-beta6`. Somebody, at some point, decided that dropping support for embedded records in ember-data was a good idea. They have implemented lots of funky hooks in order to massage the json, but after lots of trying with all possible tinkering (`extractSingle`, `extractArray`, `normalizeHash`, whatever-you-can-think-of), I have concluded that ember-data will **never** work with structured documents. Even when getting the object structured right, the sub-properties can not be accessed because ember does not see sub-models, probably because those are not supported? Whatever.

I am not talking about related documents embedded in the json response, but about a complex structured document, like this:

```
{
   "_id": "prod1",
   "_rev": "20-bcea8facfe04b3a2e3924e810dfc5ecd",
   "features": {
       "contact-numbers": 1,
       "agents": 2,
       "outgoing-call-minutes": 50,
       "basic-crm": true,
       "google-apps-integration": true,
       "call-recording": false,
       "unlimited-agents": false
   },
   "publish": true,
   "price": {
       "product": 10,
       "service": 0,
       "line": 10,
       "agent": 0,
       "minute": 0,
       "minute-806": 0.18
   },
   "product_description": "Entrepreneur",
   "active": true,
   "payment_periodicity": "MONTHLY",
   "type": "product",
   "product_name": "Entrepreneur"
}
```

This is a single document, but for ember-data, this is a no-go. In the old ember-data I could just reference `price.product` in my template, or do a `.get('price.product')` to it, or observe it, and it would just work. Not anymore. (and if it can be supported by pulling three strings at the same time, I do not care. The maintainers are [not caring](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-1-0beta-embedded-records/2359) about this, so I give up)

I still need to port my application to my last ember data, so I have thought of a solution to this: pre-flatten the document in the server, and de-flatten it when POSTing / PUTting. In order to do this automatically (and avoid going insane with yet-another hand-coded mapping), I need a character as separator which does never occur in a property name. For example, using `.`:

```
{   '_id': 'prod1',
    '_rev': '20-bcea8facfe04b3a2e3924e810dfc5ecd',
    'active': True,
    'features.agents': 2,
    'features.basic-crm': True,
    'features.call-recording': False,
    'features.contact-numbers': 1,
    'features.google-apps-integration': True,
    'features.outgoing-call-minutes': 50,
    'features.unlimited-agents': False,
    'payment_periodicity': 'MONTHLY',
    'price.agent': 0,
    'price.line': 10,
    'price.minute': 0,
    'price.minute-806': 0.18,
    'price.product': 10,
    'price.service': 0,
    'product_description': 'Entrepreneur',
    'product_name': 'Entrepreneur',
    'publish': True,
    'type': 'product'}
```

Which is so simple that even ember-data can understand it. Mmmm, *no so fast*! The dot means something to ember data, so it can not be used as separator. I have tried with:

- `X` : working, but I can not use this, since it can not be uniquely identified to de-flatten, and makes the code ugly
- `.` : special for ember-data. I guess this is used to access embedded objects.
- `/` : no luck. why?
- `#` : special in the handlebars templates, so don't do it
- `>` : nope. why?
- `:` : special for attribute bindings and other stuff, so don't try it.
- `_` : unfortunately lots of my properties have underscores (and also, ember will mangle them)
- `-` : unfortunately I was not very consistent and some of my properties have dashes - nobody is perfect! :)

What I need is a character with the following properties:

- unique enough so that I can automatically flatten / deflatten on the server
- can be safely used in templates
- can be safely used with `.get`, `.set`, `.property`, `.observes`, and any other ember-related functionality
- does not make my code unreadable: I could of course use something like `XXX` as separator, but that would make my templates and ember code really ugly.

My questions:

- Has somebody encountered this problem before? How have you solved it ?
- And most important: what character could I use as separator to avoid surprises?
- And just curious: is nobody in the ember-data team using CouchDB or MongoDB (or any NoSQL) as datastore? Structured documents are just natural in those databases.

### UPDATE

Handlebars [identifiers](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) have only certain allowed characters, so that rules out a lot of what I was trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character `§` is working fine for my purposes: it does not conflict with handlebars / ember / ember-data, and is allowed in javascript properties. So far my flattened documents are working fine.